# how publish pose topic for RRRBOT?

Tags: ros, pose, topic, robot, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how publish pose topic for [rrrbot](https://github.com/JoshMarino/gazebo_and_ros_control)  ?
i cant undrstand this page [turtle1](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259238/how-publish-pose-topic-for-rrrbot?/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2017-04-13

Post score: -2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what don't you understand? What have you tried that hasn't worked?

There's nothing in your question that actually helps us answer it, and you've been asking the same kind of question over and over, and it doesn't seem like you've taken the community's input about how to solve your problem.

I suggest you read https://jvns.ca/blog/good-questions/

Most of your previous questions have demonstrated a lack of basic understanding of ROS, TF, and general programming practice; it looks like you're just copying and pasting code together, and that almost never produces the kind of result that you're looking for.

The problem that you're trying to solve requires programming; I suggest that you pick a programming language that you're familiar with (ROS has very good support for C++ and Python), or start with an introductory programming course and get familiar with the language before you attempt a more complex program, then go through the ROS tutorials before you try to tackle the final problem.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-04-14**:
no thats not true . i dont like copy and paste . i need sample for  publish pose topic . when i understand  how example work , i trying to publish pose topic for my robot . my robot is [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/upfiles/1483594835558726.png)

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-04-14**:
i want using `rostopic hz /turtle/pose` and plot pose for links in my robot . how publish pose for links, like : `rostopic hz /rrrbot/pose`  ?? how turtle publish pose ?? and how can i publish pose frame for other robots ??

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-04-14**:
`rostopic hz` isn't going to help you plot the pose.

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-04-14**:
how can i publish pose ??

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-04-14**:
Take the rest of my advice above, and maybe you'll be able to figure it out. Otherwise, I can't help you.

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-04-14**:
i read ROS Robotics By Example , A Gentle Introduction to ROS,Effective Robotics Programming with ROS Third Edition,ROS By Example VOLUME 2&1,Robot Operating System (ROS) The Complete Reference (Volume 1) ,Learning Robotics Using Python , Learning ROS For Robotics Programmin

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-04-14**:
and Mastering ROS for Robotics ,Programming Robots with ROS

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-04-14**:
but i cant example for my question . all books have same example : turtle  !!!!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-04-14**:
You need to extrapolate from the existing tf subscriber and publisher examples to write the code you need. I think you want a TF subscriber, and a pose publisher, and you need to figure out how to incorporate those into a single program.